Remote Connection From Google Colab to Local Machine To process multicasted local network data
Even though my setting is specific to a python package called pylsl, I believe this is more of a network question.
To give an idea for those not familiar with my specific setting, I use my local machine to record brainwave (EEG) data, which is being multicasted to my local network through a library called LSL (Lab Streaming Layer) and I wish to have a remote connection to process data remotely through Google Colab. LSL broadcasts a data stream to the local network from port 16571. Normally according to LSL documentation listening from another machine is done by setting lsl_api.cfg configuration file, IP for the outlet stream device’s as ‘Known Peers’. I imagine in order to achieve the same local network effect with Google Colab some sort of tunneling-port forwarding/SSH connection is required? I know Google Colab does not support tunneling, and SSH with Pro+ account is working, but stream is still not discovered remotely when I establish ssh connection with Colab machine (Do I need to do additional steps?). This is the code that I am using:
import pylsl, os
os.environ[‘LSLAPICFG’] = ‘./lsl_api.cfg’
print(“looking for an EEG stream…”)
streams = pylsl.resolve_stream(timeout=60.0, stype=‘EEG’)
inlet = pylsl.StreamInlet(streams[0])

Which currently sort of times out without finding a stream.
Configuration file is configured according to below documentation:
https://labstreaminglayer.readthedocs.io/info/lslapicfg.html
I established SSH connection to Google Colab with below package:
https://github.com/WassimBenzarti/colab-ssh
LSL Stream is from a proprietary software from the EEG headset I have, and works fine in local network.
Any ideas/help appreciated.

Multicast is not normally routed (link-local using TTL 1) because it does not have a single destination the way unicast traffic does; it is sent to a group address. There is multicast routing, but it is very different than unicast routing. Many people try to use normal unicast routing with multicast. Multicast routing involves IGMP and a multicast router using a multicast routing protocol like PIM. Every router in the path of the multicast packets must be configured for multicast routing.

Thank you for explaining. I also heard multicasting can be tricky, pylsl sometimes doesn't work on local networks as well because a router does not allow multicast. What would be another way around to do this?
